# Error al construir el emulador en Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android

Al no ser capaz de resolver los problemas que he tenido con la version 2.2, a pesar de vuestra ayuda, la cual agradezco profundamente, he cambiado la versión y he colocado la version 2.1. Todo ha funcionado bien hasta el momento de ejecutar la app. Cuando intenta crear el emulador me aparece lo siguiente:

getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

Os agradecería una vez mas vuestra ayuda, ya que tengo en proyecto trasladar a una app un programa que creé hace tiempo de IA, mejor dicho tipo chattbot. De echo tengo dos, uno programado con Delphi y otro con Python.
Gracias a todos
Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Edita tu AVD, en configuraciones avanzadas, vas a la parte de RAM y le pones 512

Comment: Guardas cambios y corres de nuevo tu emlador, y me dices como te fue

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me dices pero sigue igual con el mismo mensaje. Lo curioso es que hay un momento en el que aparece el emulador pero desaparece rápidamente.